# Devolver un valor 0 o 1 si se cumple una sentencia CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql

¿Como devolver un valor **0** o **1** si se cumple una sentencia? Tengo una tabla de 2 columnas, una inicial y una final que determinan un rango de numeros. Ejemplo: Inicial 100 - Final 200, lo que busco es que al consultar si un valor Ejemplo. 150 se encuentra entre este rango me devuelve un valor 1 y sino 0.

```
SELECT MiResultado =
CASE WHEN 150 BETWEEN Inicial AND Final then 1
ELSE 0
END
FROM prueba
```

Lo anterior me muestra el resultado de la consulta en todas las filas de la tabla, ejemplo:

```
Inicio Final MiResultado   

50     200   1

200    250   0

300    500   0

800    900   0
```

Pero solo necesite que me retorne 1 si se cumple la condición o 0 , ejemplo:

```
MiResultado  

1
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo que queres devolver, sobre todo por que si, lo que haces te va a mostrar para todas las filas. Para restringir las filas, se usa where.

Comment: Podes aclara sql para que base de datos? Las respuestas que te dieron no son correctas.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta con la nueva información.

Answer (score 2):

Debes asignar lo que devuelve el `CASE` a un alias, quizás por eso no ves nada, adicional, el BETWEEN va a dar FALSE cuando el valor inicial es mayor que el valor de comparación, aunque la segunda columna sea menor.
Ejemplo:

> 150 BETWEEN 80 AND 190 -- TRUE
>
> 150 BETWEEN 70 AND 100 -- FALSE
>
> 150 BETWEEN 190 AND 80 -- FALSE (aunque debería ser TRUE)

Si estás seguro que los datos de la primera columna SIEMPRE van a ser menores que los de la segunda, entonces puedes quitar el segundo `BETWEEN`. De lo contrario, esta modificación debe funcionar.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN 150 BETWEEN Inicial AND Final THEN 1 
    WHEN 150 BETWEEN Final AND Inicial THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
END AS MiResultado 
FROM prueba
```

[EDIT] Si solo quieres los resultados que cumplen la condición de estar entre las dos columnas, entonces hay que cambiar un poquito el SQL añadiendo un `WHERE` y también se puede eliminar el `CASE`

```
SELECT Final, Inicial, 1 AS MiResultado 
FROM prueba 
WHERE 
(150 BETWEEN Inicial AND Final)
OR 
(150 BETWEEN Final AND Inicial)
```

Comment: Esto le va a devolver todas las filas. No una sola.

Comment: Ahora vas mejor. Pero si ninguna fila cumple la condicion, no le va a devolver nada ;)

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta, agregué ambos casos.

Comment: testbed http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fabe4/4 el /4 son mis pifies =P

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que te refieres a que si un registro de tu tabla cumple con tu condicion entonces solo quiere un 1 en caso contrario 0

```
select  case when  ( select max(Valor) from Prueba) > 150 then 1 else 0 end
```

saludos.